# Unable to create diagram

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm getting this error:

> 'Category' table saved successfully
> 'Author' table saved successfully
>
> 'Product' table -
> Unable to create relationship 'FK_Product_Author'.   The ALTER TABLE
> statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
> "FK_Product_Author". The conflict occurred in database "Sample_1",
> table "dbo.Author", column 'AuthorID'.

How can I fix this ??

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  We're glad to have you :)  Please, edit your question with the SQL script that produces this output. Definitions for each of these three tables would also be helpful (e.g., a CREATE TABLE script with the relevant keys and relationships)

Comment: Since the OP is talking about diagrams, and an error within, I doubt that a SQL Script exists - I think it's all GUI in SSMS.

Comment: What does the following return? `SELECT * FROM Product WHERE AuthorID NOT IN (SELECT a.AuthorID FROM dbo.Author a)`

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you have information in your database and you try to create a diagram.

You have an inconsistence between Product and Author tables, I mean, you have an AuthorId inside Product Table that dooes not exist in Author Table, so when you try to create a Foreign Key, you can't create it.